# Xcode - Is there a way to get the extension of a resource?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resources

Hey all, this should be pretty simple to answer:

Is there a property of a NSURL such as lastPathComponent and StringByDeletingPathExtension that actually gives you just the extension instead?

If so, what is it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `-pathExtension` method:

> **pathExtension** Returns the path
>   extension of a file URL.